# Evolution after upgradeing to Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: software-updater

After upgrading to U 13.04 Evolution starts up and immediately shuts down...?To send a message from the launch bar is the only activity functioning.

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance, Gerrit

Comment: What if run `evolution` from gnome-terminal? Is there any output?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after I upgraded to Ubuntu 13.04 from Ubuntu 12.10 just yesterday. If I opened Evolution, it came up and closed itself within one second.  Anyhow I was able to open the Calendar, the Contacts and the "Compose New Mail" part of Evolution directly from the launcher without crashing. But as soon as I changed to the Email window, Evolution crashed again. It also crashed, when I tried to access the preferences (after I started Evolution Calender or Contacts directly).

I found the following bug with some workaround that did not help me either, but perhaps they will help you?

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evolution/+bug/1166447

Anyhow the information from this bug report helped me to solve this issue:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evolution/+bug/1173551

I used the Synaptic Package Manager to completely remove Evolution (just the main package including two linked packages auto-selected by Synaptic). After that I did a reboot of my machine and used the Ubuntu Software Center to install Evolution again. After this procedure Evolution started without any problems. All my e-mail accounts as well as my locally stored e-mails were still there.
Nevertheless I made a backup of ~/.local/share/evolution prior to the procedure mentioned above.

Hope that helps!